# Why can't I launch amr-ros-config-master and ROSARIA?

Tags: urdf, rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone

Recently I've been trying to connect ROSARIA and AdeptMobileRobots.I have downloaded amr-ros-config-master file from [https://github.com/MobileRobots/amr-ros-config], however,when I launch this launched file,the following error came:

**Invalid  tag: amr_robots_description**

**ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros**

**ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/indigo/share**

**ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks**

**Arg xml is arg default="$(find amr_robots_description)/urdf/pioneer3dx.urdf" name="urdf"/**

**The traceback for the exception was written to the log file**

ANYONE can help me???
THANKS VERY MUCH.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251707/why-can%27t-i-launch-amr-ros-config-master-and-rosaria?/) by [edmond320](https://answers.ros.org/users/4100/edmond320/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2017-01-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2017-03-13**:
Hello, are you trying to use one of the launch files? If so which one, what is the exact command you are using, and what is the output of that?  The amr-ros-config repository contains ROS packages, which must be in the ROS package path. (e.g. the src directory of a catkin workspace)

**Comment by [bongzaseko](https://answers.ros.org/users/29704/bongzaseko/) on 2017-03-24**:
I am also getting the same error. The command is: roslaunch rosaria.launch and the output is exactly as shown in the question. The packages have been cloned into the src directory and properly built through catkin_make at the base catkin path

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2017-03-24**:
bongzaseko: Is `amr-ros-config` in the `src` directory? did you run `. devel/setup.bash` or similar in the catkin workspace?  What is the output of `rospack find amr_robots_description`? What version of ROS are you using? Also indigo?

**Comment by [bongzaseko](https://answers.ros.org/users/29704/bongzaseko/) on 2017-03-24**:
This has been sorted on my side, I hadn't followed the tutorial on rosaria setup properly. After redoing it the error went away, now i can startup the rosaria node. Yes I am using Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2017-03-24**:
Can you write an answer below with a quick explanation? Which step in the rosaria tutorial fixed it?

**Comment by [bongzaseko](https://answers.ros.org/users/29704/bongzaseko/) on 2017-03-24**:
OK, I will do so in a few moments. Let me draft it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I experienced the same problem and got it cleared by redoing the ROSARIA setup using the instructions in http://wiki.ros.org/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA. I started from the "Bring ROSARIA into the workspace" section since I already had ROS installed and my catkin workspace setup. Under the next section(Install ARIA and Build ROSARIA), I installed the ARIA dependecy using the given rosdep commands, and after that built ROSARIA using the --force-cmake option on catkin_make as advised. I then proceeded successfully with all the following steps in this tutorial on starting the rosaria node and publishing as well as with running the roslaunch rosaria.launch file from the amr_robots_launchfiles package.

---

Originally posted by [bongzaseko](https://answers.ros.org/users/29704/bongzaseko/) with karma: 26 on 2017-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1